# Replacing awk with bash built-ins

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have been told to write a bash script for adding all the GroupID's in "**/etc/passwd**" file, this is my scrip

```
 #!/bin/sh
 # script input should be (sh groupsum.sh /etc/passwd)

 if [ -f $1 ] ; then
     awk -F ':' '{print $4}' $1 > /tmp/numb
     A=`awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}' /tmp/numb`
     echo $A
 else
     echo "its not a file"
 fi
```

The script is working fine but to make it fast I should use bash built-in commands instead of using "**awk**". So I need information to achieve this using built-in commands it would be great if someone gives the explanation on this.

Comment: I think `awk -F: '{print s+=$4} END{print s}' /etc/passwd` is pretty fast.

Comment: Do you really need to do this so many times that the performance of native bash vs awk matters?

Comment: What possible use is there for adding the group ids together? Sounds like a poorly designed homework assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said "bash built-ins", but your script starts with `#!/bin/sh` -- which requests POSIX sh, not bash. I'll assume, though, that you really *do* want bash.

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ -f "$1" ]] || { echo "Not a file" >&2; exit 1; }
exec <"$1"
total=0
while IFS=':' read -r _ _ _ groupid _; do
  (( total += groupid ))
done
echo "$total"
```

To explain the specific operations being used to replace components of your awk script: The `read` command iterates through lines (by default), splitting them by characters in `IFS`; so `IFS=: read -r _ _ _ groupid _` discards the first three columns, puts the fourth in in a variable named `groupid`, and discards the rest. `(( ))` is a math context in bash; inside it, C-style syntax is usable for integer arithmetic operations, hence the addition.

---

By the way, reading `/etc/passwd` directly is a bad idea -- it won't work on systems using LDAP, or NIS, or any other alternate directory service. If you're on a Linux host, you can use the `getent` program to do a lookup that works with whatever your current directory service is:

```
$ yourscript <(getent passwd)
```

All that said, the premise for this question is a poor one -- though there's overhead for spawning any external program, awk included, once it's running awk is much, much faster than bash. If speed were your only priority, you'd do better to not use a shell at all, and have your script start with a shebang that runs the awk interpreter directly.

Comment: I have been told not to create a subprocess from the script, If I'm using awk it will create a subprocess and that simply increase the CPU utilization for few moments, It will be a concern for minimal Unix OS which we are using.

Comment: @PrabhuAre, if it's too expensive to run awk as a subprocess, it's probably too expensive to be using bash anyhow. I would consider writing this as a pure awk script (`#!/usr/bin/awk -f` rather than `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh`) so instead of starting bash and having it start awk, you **only** run awk, which will be faster than **only** running bash, as the script here does.